# The different access right to onActivityResult in FragmentActivity with Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult

Why the function **onActivityResult** in **FragmentActivity** is **protected**

meanwhile the function **onActivityResult** in **Fragment** is **public**?

Comment: Because the activity need to access its fragment, included the fragment's methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the activity need to access its fragment, included the fragment's methods.

Thanks to @Anggrayudi H.